# Export comments as comments

Tags: emacs, latex, comments, org-mode

In Org-mode you can make comments and from Org-mode you can export to LaTeX but Org-mode comments are not exported to LaTeX comments. How can Org-mode be made to export Org-mode comments as LaTeX comments?

Here is an example. The following

```
* Test

Text before comment
# Comment
Text after comment

Text before comment
#+BEGIN_COMMENT
Comment
#+END_COMMENT
Text after comment
```

exports to

```latex
\section{Test}
\label{sec-1}


Text before comment
Text after comment

Text before comment

Text after comment
```

But I want the Org-mode comments to be exported as LaTeX comments. Thus, I want the following LaTeX output:

```latex
\section{Test}
\label{sec-1}


Text before comment
% Comment
Text after comment

Text before comment
\begin{comment}
Comment
\end{comment}
Text after comment
```

I am running Org-mode 7.6 in Emacs 23.3.1.

Comment: AFAIK its not possible. But I like the idea of comments being exported as comments in the output format(those support comments in the documents)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the current exporter the only method I can think of that would allow you to export comments would be backend-specific.  You could use something along the lines of:

```
#+latex: comment
```

or

```
#+begin_latex
\begin{comment}
  comment
\end{comment}
#+end_latex
```

However both are contrived and you would need to do the equivalent for HTML etc if you intend to export to more than one format.

There is a [new exporter](http://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg49283.html) in development however where this should not be overly difficult to implement (comments are already identified as blocks in the parser so it would simply need a method to convert them on export).

I'm forwarding this request to the mailing list to see if this can be included.
Edit: Thread located [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/53936).

Edit: Response from the maintainer of Org-Mode

> the current exporters don't allow this, but the new export engine by
>   Nicolas makes it possible.
>
> The plan is to merge the new export engine into Org's core before
>   version 8.0, so please stay tuned.

Comment: I did a search and replace on `\n# ` to make it `\n#+latex:% `. That turns all lines starting with `# ` in org-mode to lines starting with `% ` in emacs, which accomplished what I think is N.N.'s task.

Comment: This does not work for me. In the exported pdf I still get the unwanted text.

Comment: @bobsacameno This was based on a version of OrgMode < 8.0.  With the changes to the export engine since then the process would be different.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Jonathan Leech-Pepin's answer, there is a hackish way of doing it for a given exporter backend.  Comments are handled in the `org-export-handle-comments` function, which is called by `org-export-preprocess-string` in org-exp.el.  Each exporter backend is different, but let us consider the LaTeX backend.

If you look in the `org-export-as-latex` function in org-latex.el, you can find calls to `org-export-preprocess-string`.  One of the things passed to the `org-export-preprocess-string` function is a parameter list, in particular it contains a `:comments` parameter, which in the LaTeX case is set to `nil`.  This parameter tells the org-mode exporter what to do with comments - for the details look at the call to and implementation of `org-export-handle-comments` in org-exp.el.  Essentially, the `:comments` parameter can be a format string showing how to handle the comments; if it is `nil`, this means no format handling so nothing is printed.  If, in the `org-export-as-latex` function, you replace `:comments nil` with `:comments "%% %s"`, then this will insert a "%" in front of whatever the comment text is upon export.  So in your case

```
this is text before a comment
# this is a comment
this is text after a comment
```

would be exported as

```
this is text before a comment
% this is a comment
this is text after a comment
```

This isn't the most convenient way of doing things, and I'm not sure of a way to specify the `:comments` parameter on a per-file basis.  Maybe something in the thread Jonathan set up will shed some light on this subject.

Note that you may need to remove the byte-compiled org-latex.elc file in order to see your changes in org-latex.el propagate through to the export.